# can someone help me to fix this error from nextjs and reactquery?

Tags: javascript

in this code, I created a multiple hooks with react query, and I import them in my component, but the error occurred when I am calling the useAddStudent and useDeleteStudent (in different component) at the same time (this the error:
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
   )

```
import services from "./services";
import { useQuery, useMutation, useQueryClient, QueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query';

export const useAllStudents = () => {
  return useQuery({ 
    queryKey: ['students'],
    queryFn: services.getAllStudents, //api call
    // staleTime: Infinity,  // it won't refetch your query and throw cache result
  });
}

export const useAddStudent = () => {
  const { invalidateQueries } = useQueryClient();
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: (data: object) => services.addStudents(data), //api call
    onSuccess: () => {
      invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['students'] });
    }
  })
}

export const useDeleteStudent = () => {
  const { invalidateQueries } = useQueryClient();
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: (id: string) => services.deleteStudent(id), //api call
    onSuccess: () => {
      invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['students'] });
    }
  })
}
```

```
// this from delete component
const { mutate: mutation } = useDeleteStudent();
async function handleClick(id: any) {
  console.log('You have clicked this delete button');
  mutation(id);
}

// this from form component
 const { mutate: mutation } = useAddStudent();
  async function handleSubmit(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mutation(form)
  }
```

I have tried to read this information from the  react query documentation. but it's a bit confusing

The useQueryClient hook returns the current QueryClient instance.

```
tsx
import { useQueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query'
```

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient(queryClient?: QueryClient)
```

Options

queryClient?: QueryClient,
Use this to use a custom QueryClient. Otherwise, the one from the nearest context will be used.